# Tab Sound stops on multiple clicks

Tags: android, android-widget

I was running some tests and noticed that after I click my tabs about..hmm..10 times maybe? My click sound disappears all together. Do I need to add some type of onpauses or something? What should I add to this code to make it work?

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            //PLAY SOUND HERE
            final MediaPlayer tabClick = MediaPlayer.create(TabBarActivity.this, R.raw.click);
            tabClick.start();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative technique that does work is to allocate a [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) object into which you load your sounds at Activity creation time. Then you can play those sounds at any point thereafter, as many times as you like.

For example, see how the click sound is implemented in [ti5x](https://github.com/ldo/ti5x_android/blob/master/src/ButtonGrid.java).